# Can I install software on a bootable usb key?

Tags: installation, live-usb, persistence

I have a question.
Say I make a bootable usbkey, what would happen if I install some software with synaptic ? will it persists over boots (like if it was a real hard drive).
Or should I create another "data" partition on the usb key ?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

In "Startup Disk Creator", there is an option called "Persistence". If you select that and create the bootable USB drive, all your software, settings, and documents will remain permanent, like an installed Ubuntu system.

Comment: It's called "Persistence".

Comment: Can I do this using an alternative install ? I am willing to create an encripted usb stick

Comment: @user123492 Thanks, in Kubuntu's startup disk creator it's called "store documents and settings in reserved space", so I assumed it must be the same for the Ubuntu version (I thought the Kubuntu version simply uses Qt instead of GTK, but was otherwise the same).